# Webpart built using latest spfx version not working on the classic site

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, angularjs, spfx-tooling

I have built an angular 1.x webpart application using the spfx 1.4 version. The webpart works in the modern sites pages but is not working on the classic site pages and I am getting the following error.

```
[SPWebPartErrorCode.IncorrectBoostrapModule]:

Bootstrap module for web part WebPart.CsTaskBoardWebPart.g_76cddb14_eed9_4284_81a4_b8db3ff64e8c not of the correct type. Make sure to export your web part as 'export default WebPartName'.
***CALLSTACK:

t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2018-05-18.011/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9bd26145452b8a6a140c7ec7a2b736fb.js:201:15770
t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2018-05-18.011/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9bd26145452b8a6a140c7ec7a2b736fb.js:301:9108
......
```

my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "^1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "^1.4.1",
"@types/jquery": "^2.0.48",
"@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.2",
"@types/react": "0.14.46",
"@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
"@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
"@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
"@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
"@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
"angular": "^1.6.10",
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-dom": "15.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
"@types/angular": "^1.6.43",
"@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
"@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
"ajv": "~5.2.2",
"gulp": "~3.9.1"
}
```

I was using the 1.4 version for development but the "includeClientSideAssets": true, property was not working in package-solution.json file and was giving error like "not available etc". So I updated all the modules starting with sp including generator sharepoint and the includeClientSideAssets property worked

Please tell me how to make the webpart work on the classic site pages. any suggestions or idea?

Comment: Delete the page and create it once again. Then add your web part to the page. I hope it will work.

Comment: I have tried it multiple times. it doesn't work